# Is it possible to find specific text in a txt and use only that text from a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a txt file that contains something similar to this

> [A]
>
> something1
>
> something2
>
> [B]
>
> anotherthing1
>
> anotherthing2

etc

is it possible from a batch file to say something like

```
 if name = B
 iterate over the b section in the file
```

I know how to loop through the entire file

```
FOR /F %%g in (textfile.txt) do stuff
```

but I don't now if its possible to find a section and use it

Comment: I think you would need something a little more unique that defines each section.  Just using letters could cause undesired results.  If you have ever looked at an INI file, they usually define the start of a section with brackets. `[section1]`

Comment: Yes, in theory. But it depends on section names (if there's a pattern to be found in order to identify them), and how they differ from regular lines (that's are not section names). Your example is a (too) simple one, and a piece of code that would do the trick is not hard to write, but trying to extend it to be more general would generate a lot of headaches.

Comment: @Squashman so if I did something like that, how would I find that section and use it?

Comment: @user6641597, we have an extract file section routine over on Dostips.com.  It uses a start and end mark. http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.extractFileSection

Comment: @Squashman this was exactly what I needed thank you.

Comment: @Squashman im sorry this got marked as a duplicate for a question that has an answer that the requester said didnt work so I cant give you the points/credit

Comment: @user6641597, I don't come here to help to get points. The gaming aspect of SO does not appeal to me.  I just come here to help and learn.